# Why is an interface ignored by -i any with tcpdump/wireshark?

Tags: tcpdump

Using **tcpdump** and **wireshark**, if I capture with `-i enp1s0f0`, no problem I can see the packets.
If I capture with `-i any`, I don't see the **enp1s0f0**'s packets.

Why? Is there a NetworkManager option or something that discards that interface?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually configure Wireshark to monitor additional interfaces. By default it'll only monitor one.

See this guide for more info: https://www.samkear.com/networking/test
In short though, press Ctrl+I and enable the extra interfaces to capture.

Comment: What is the purpose of `any` then? And how about tcpdump?